# DataTable Constraint exception on different values in primary column

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, primary-key, unique-constraint

Setting the primary key means the column values must be unique.

It seems DataTable does not enforce the key to be *different* but that they *compare as non-zero* using the DataTable.Locale comparison rules.

The DataTable.Locale.CompareInfo.Compare may return 0 even if the strings are different as they would sort the same.

Is there a way to change the behavior? I could not find how to replace the CompareInfo.

The example data I have include some characters that are in category *UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned*.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace datatabletest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            string key = "key";
            string metric = "metric";

            string key1 = "\u0a0dtest\u0a0d;";
            string key2 = "test\u0a0d;";

            DataTable table = new DataTable("table");

            table.Columns.Add( key);
            table.Columns.Add( metric );
            table.PrimaryKey = new[] { table.Columns[key] };

            table.BeginLoadData();

            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row[key] = key1;
                row[metric] = "500";
                table.Rows.Add( row );
            }

            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row[key] = key2;
                row[metric] = "500";
                table.Rows.Add( row );
            }

            // strings are different
            Console.WriteLine( key1 ==  key2 );

            //but they compare method still returns 0
            Console.WriteLine( table.Locale.CompareInfo.Compare( key1, key2 ) );

            // throws a ConstraintException
            table.EndLoadData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2 reads
 Ignorable characters include:
A string with code points that have no linguistic significance. For example, a soft hyphen (U+00AD) is always ignored in a culture-sensitive string comparison.

Comment: In your second data row example you are using `row[metric]` twice. I guess it should be `row[key]`. But yeah, it doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks Sergey for spotting the typo. However as you said it does not resolve the issue.